# Can you use "the" + "both" + noun?

Tags: prepositions, word-order, determiners, legalese

I came across this sentence "Now therefore, the both parties enter into..." and it seemed incorrect to me.  Shouldn't it be "both (of) the parties" or "both parties"?  Or is it correct to say "the both parties"?

Comment: It's definitely incorrect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"..the both parties.." is incorrect. Here, *both* has already qualified *parties* and is clear what/who is being referred to. Nevertheless, people use it in an informal way.

> Shouldn't it be "both (of) the parties" or "both parties"?

Both your options are correct. "both the parties" is short for "both of the parties" and is completely acceptable. On the other hand, *the* seems to be extraneous and hence, can be removed altogether, just leaving us with "both parties".

Answer (score 0):

Longman says

• You use both or both of before a determiner such as ‘the’, ‘these’, or ‘my’: Both (of) the women were tall.Both (of) her parents are dead. ✗ Don’t say: the both women | her both parents

Comment: This adds nothing to the accepted answer.